# Selenium test on existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I've just went through [Acumatica TestSDK Documentation](http://acumatica-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=builds/17.2/17.207.0029/TestSDK/) and did some tests on the project which was given as a sample. Everything went OK, but as soon as I decided to write tests on my existing project, some problems occurred.

More specifically, I couldn't generate wrapper classes for my pages. When I run ClassGenerator.exe that error shows up:

> System.Exception: Unable to get screen NG101000 with url /Pages/NG/NG101000.aspx ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

I had the same problem earlier when I was writing tests for sample project but the problem was that it was an empty project and as soon as I filled it with demo data, everything worked. I think it's not the case here because that project is not empty.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the correct company in your Acumatica instance?  For some reason the SDK code hard codes the companyid.  When I switched from trying out sample code to writing code for my customizations, this tripped me up.

Comment: Yeah, that was the reason, I've already solved it. Thanks.